# I don't know how to deal with jquery ajax POST error "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" when calling ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I tried doing a `POST` call to my ASP.NET MVC app using jQuery and Ajax, creating a new entry in the backend (SQL Server), but the Google Chrome console shows an error

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I did a `GET` command and it works just fine.

Here is my jQuery Ajax for my POST call

```
function insert() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var ownerCreate = {
                  owner : $("input[name=emailfm]").val(),
                  testModelArea : $("input[name=subjecttitle]").val()
            }
                
        $.ajax({
                  url: "https://localhost:7206/api/Owner?locationId=" + $("input[name=firstname]").val(),
                  type: "POST",
                  // dataType: "json",
                  data: JSON.stringify(ownerCreate),
                  headers: {
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  },
                  success:function(response){
                    if(response == 1){
                      alert("Data Added Successfully");
                    }
                    else {
                      alert("placeholder error");
                    }
                  }
        });
    });
}
```

Here is my ASP.NET MVC `POST` method that I'm calling using jQuery Ajax:

```
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(204)]
[ProducesResponseType(400)]
public IActionResult CreateOwner([FromQuery] int locationId, [FromBody] OwnerDto ownerCreate)
{
    if (ownerCreate == null)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var owner = _ownerRepos.GetOwners()
                           .Where(t => t.Owner.Trim().ToUpper() == ownerCreate.Owner.TrimEnd().ToUpper())
                           .FirstOrDefault();

    if (owner != null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Model Owner", "Owner already exists");
        return StatusCode(422, ModelState);
    }

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var ownerMap = _mapper.Map<ConnectTestModel1>(ownerCreate);

    ownerMap.Location = _locationRepos.GetLocation(locationId);

    if (!_ownerRepos.CreateOwner(ownerMap))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Can't save");
        return StatusCode(500, ModelState);
    }

    return Ok("Successfully created");
}
```

When using the jQuery Ajax, I filled in my locationId, Owner and testModelArea and sent it through a button. The Google Chrome console said that my payload went through, the only problem I have is the connection error.

This is my first question using Stackoverflow, so if I'm lacking in certain aspects, please let me know.

Comment: Wrong endpoint url?

Comment: What @Selvin said, the call is to https://localhost:7206/api/Owner and the endpoint is CreateOwner

Comment: Hey there, I used the swagger controller to run the same POST call and it works normally, I checked the endpoints and it's 
https://localhost:7206/api/Owner?locationId=25, everything's fine if I'm using the swagger UI

Comment: Do me a favour and try returning `NoContent("Successfully created")` (code 204) instead of `Ok("Successfully created")` (code 200). Let's see what that does

Comment: Or else add `[ProducesResponseType(200)]` to the method attributes

Comment: Hey yall, thanks for the reply, it works fine now, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remind if you create api controller you need to delete `[ApiController]` attribute to make ajax work.

I tested your code and works well. Maybe you could try following simple way.

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class OwnerController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public void CreateOwner(int locationId, OwnerDto ownerCreate)
        {
        }
    }
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var ownerCreate = {
            owner : "testowner",
            testModelArea : "testmodel"
    }

$.ajax('https://localhost:7275/api/owner', {
            type: 'POST',  
            data: {
                locationId:7,
                ownerCreate:ownerCreate           
            } 
        });
</script>
```

[image]